# than are earlier variants

Tags: grammar

Many vaccines have been shown to provide strong protection against COVID-19. Now, growing evidence finds that they also substantially reduce the risk of passing on the virus SARS-CoV-2 — crucial information for governments making decisions about how best to control the pandemic.

However, the studies were done before the highly transmissible Delta variant became prevalent — and scientists say it might be more easily spread by vaccinated people **than are earlier variants**.

Source: Nature   [COVID vaccines slash viral spread – but Delta is an unknown](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-02054-z)

Is the complete grammatical structure of the phrase "than are earlier variants" "than earlier variants are spread by vaccinated people"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, good filling-in of the ellipsis.

This kind of inversion is common, if a bit formal / written rather than spoken. It's triggered by the fact that the second subject is so long that if "are" were placed after it, it might be hard to parse the comparison.

> Star Trek: The Original Series places a stronger emphasis on bravado and interspecies conflict than does The Next Generation.

Also, you might be tempted to drop the placeholder "does" altogether. That's possible, but again slightly less formal, and technically it creates ambiguity about whether the second subject is actually an object.